# how to debug multiple processes in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a c# program1 that starts up another c# program2.exe and executes methods in it.  I can't figure out how to debug it.  Here is the code from the calling program1:

```
  Task = new Process () ;

  Task.StartInfo.FileName = Executable ;
  Task.StartInfo.Arguments = AddQuotes (Msg) ;

  if (GeneralRegistry.GetWaitForExit ())
  { State.WaitForExit () ;
  }

  bool OK = Task.Start () ;
```

Task.StartInfo.Filename is the name of the program2.exe that is executed.
Task.StartInfo.Arguments is xml that includes the name of another xml "model" file.  The model defines variables, equations, and data.  Program2.exe parses the xml model and executes it.

I'm using VS12 Express.  I tried Debug>Attach to Process and attached to Program2.exe after it starts up.  I click the "Go" menu item in Program2.exe to start the analysis.  Now what?  How do I set breakpoints and step through Program2.exe?  I do not have the source code for it.

However, I do have source code for Program3.  That program is somehow embedded in Program2.exe.  Program2.exe has the UI and inputs but the core underlying work is done by Program3.

Comment: `That program is somehow embedded in Program2.exe` Do you really think we can tell you how to debug your program if you don't even know how you're running it?

Comment: [Can not debug a Project started using Process.Start()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506882/can-not-debug-a-project-started-using-process-start)

Answer (score 0):

If both these programs are in the same solution, you can attach the exe to the debugger and step into program2 dll from program 1. Do you initialize program 2's object in program 1?

Comment: OP has indicated that he does not have the source code for it so can't see how an .exe can be part of the same solution.  - _"I do not have the source code for it [Programe2.exe]"_