# How to attach a child process in existing Debugger?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-debugging, child-process

I've been looking at the solution provided by Scott Chamberlain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506882/can-not-debug-a-project-started-using-process-start) to attach the existing debugger to a process, B, which A starts.

In the `ICommand` of A I've these:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\...\General.exe", Name);
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

and B's `DataContext` is set to `Code.cs` in the View like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Code/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

and in the Constructor I've these:

```
Debugger.Launch();
Name = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).First();
```

It launches the JIT debugger BUT in the `GroupBox` of `Possible Debuggers` I always get one option:

> New Instance of ...

How can I get the existing debugger, attached to `A`, in the `Possible Debuggers` list? 
Both A and B are in same Solution.

Comment: Maybe you can try using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the workaround described in **Scott's** answer, you can also try using extension: [Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool&ssr=false#overview).This extension allows Visual Studio to automatically debug child processes after we enabled the option in `Debug=>Other Debug Targets=>Child Process Debugging Settings`.(We need to make sure to choose the mixed mode if we're debugging .net code)

For now, it supports VS2013~VS2019. More details you could check [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/). Hope it helps :)

Comment: where's that mixed mode? Under the `DebuggerType`, there're `Inherit...`, `Managed`, `Native`, `Managed + Native` and `Script`!  Is `Managed + Native` mixed mode?

Comment: I'm on `.net core`, first I went with the default `all process ... Inherit`, then tried every option under `DebuggerType`, didn't work. Then added the app name `General.exe` in the second row and for all process selected `Do not debug` and tried all options on `DebuggerType`, that also didn't work! Then specified the full path `C:\...\General.exe` and did the same BUT no success!

Comment: Hi, for .net core projects, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2017#to-configure-mixed-mode-debugging-for-a-net-core-app).

Comment: This extension has problem, VS 2019 now crashes whenever I click save on `Child Process Debugging Settings`! Only the first time when I installed it, I'd been able to click to save, Now VS suggests to disable the extension.

Comment: I test it in VS2019 with .net framework, but can't reproduce the issue. It works. Sorry for that I haven't  tested the situation with .net core today for some reason, I will test .net core tomorrow and update it here :-)

Comment: @EmonHaque Strange that it works in my machine with VS2019 16.3.9 though I actually didn't set the launchsettings.json file.  1.right-click project=>properties=>debug=>enable the native debugging 2.Since the output of wpf(.net core) is different from wpf(.net fx), I copy all the output of second project into first project's output folder. 3. The extension works well in my machine, it doesn't crash... (make sure you've enabled enable child process debugging), trying reinstalling...

Comment: 4. Instead of using Process.start, I use `ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
            startInfo.FileName = "WpfBpp.exe";
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }`

Comment: I'm not sure if the behavior you met results from the code, if possible, please share a minimal sample so that I can check it directly for you :)

Comment: OK, I'll try it tomorrow or day after tomorrow and let you know the update.

Comment: In both projects' properties, I'd to set `Enable native code debugging` (I didn't do that for both before)! In `Child Process Debugging Settings` I gave the full path of the `.exe` like this `C:\...\General.exe` under Process Name, `Attach Debugger` under Action and `<Inherit from parent process>` under Debugger Type. Now it works and I don't have to have `Debugger.Launch()` in constructor, it just get to the breakpoint automatically! I neither copied the output to the caller project's output folder nor used `ProcessStartInfo`, it works fine with `Process.Start`! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know it helps :)

Comment: This solution is great but it makes debugging SO slow, either that or MS's symbol servers are slow as heck. A better alternative where no native code debugging flag is set to true should exist somehow :(